External Cavity Laser: Phase Condition
Question: For a laser in which, for example the right mirror has a wavelength dependent transfer function T(λ) and thus a effective length Leff(λ). The below equation is valid or I should use another method for the modes extraction?
$θ_{rt}$ = $(\dfrac{2π}{λ})$ $*$ $[L_{Total Laser Length}] = m*2π$
$θ_{rt}$ = $(\dfrac{2π}{λ})$ $*$ $[2n_{eff,a} * L_a + 2n_{eff,b} * L_b] = m*2π$
Where,
$L_b = L_{bus} + \dfrac{1}{2}ΣL_{r,eﬀ}$
$L_{r,eff} = L_r*\dfrac{-p}{(2*p^2-2)sin^2(\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{2π}{λ}n_{eff,b}L_r+ φ_r))+2}$
$p = \dfrac{k^2-2}{k^2}$
$n_{eff,a} = 3.155$             Effective Index of Gain Medium 
$n_{eff,b} = 1.535$             Effective Index of Passive Medium
$L_{a} = 0.7 mm$                Geometrical length of Gain Medium
$L_{bus} = 6.7 mm$              Geometrical bus waveguide length
$L_{r1} = 885.6 um$             Roundtrip length of MRR 1
$L_{r2} = 857.7 um$             Roundtrip length of MRR 2
$φ_{r1} = 281.45 deg$           Phase from MRR 1 Heater
$φ_{r2} = 141.77 deg$           Phase from MRR 2 Heater
$k = 0.071$                     Power coupling coefficient between bus and MRR\
(If it is off topic post, tell me to delete it, Thanks!)
The laser has the below form:


Could you provide more context about what you're asking? It seems to use a very specific notation. If you can provide your source material, what are you studying...
